# Apache ~ How to Not Start Apache on Computer Boot

Tags: apache, windows-7

I finished coding my website for awhile and would like to stop Apache from starting when my computer boots because it slows down my other startup applications.  I have looked through the Apache Wiki, the source files, and the htaccess file.  Maybe I am not finding it, but is there any way to do this without uninstalling Apache?

I am using Windows 7 as an OS.

*I just want to mention that this is different than simply stopping or starting or restarting Apache.  I know how to do that.  I would just like it not to start up on boot until I start working on my website again.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open msconfig (start->type "msconfig"->click "msconfig.exe")

Check "Startup" tab for Apache or "Services" tab if you can't find it, and disable it.